# Django ORM | No se muestra url de imagen en template pero sí name y otras columnas

Tags: python, django

Tengo el siguiente modelo, view y template, con los cuales no hay problema es conseguir el "name" o "station" de la imagen correspondiente. En cambio no consigo recuperar la URL con la cual poder mostrar la imagen. ¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Gracias.

**model.py**

```
lass ImageStation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, related_name="station_image",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    image_imageStation = models.ImageField(upload_to='stations/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen estación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagen de estaciones'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image_imageStation)
```

**views.py**

```
class StationGalleryListView(ListView):
    model = ImageStation
    template_name = 'station/gallery_station.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        object_list = self.model.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return object_list
```

**gallery_station.html**

```
    {% for images in object_list.all %}
          <img src="{% static 'media/stations/estacionagua.jpg' %}"><br>  <!-- NO MUESTRA NADA -->
          <img src="{% static 'media/{{ images }}' %}"><br>  <!-- NO MUESTRA NADA -->
        {{ images }} <!--MUESTRA URL stations/estacionagua.jpg -->
        {{ images.name }} <!-- MUESTRA name BIEN -->
        {{ images.station }} <!-- MUESTRA nombre estación BIEN -->
    {% endfor %}
                  {{ station.name_station }}
```

(La ruta de imagen es media>stations>estacionagua.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La ruta no era correcta. Colocando sin "url" la imagen se muestra perféctamente de la siguiente manera:

```
{% for images in object_list.all %}
    <img src="/media/{{ images }}"><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: El problema de esta solución es qué ocurre si cambias la URL a la carpeta MEDIA.

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar los archivos de imagen, se utiliza el valor `{{ image.url }}` aunque el campo en el modelo de datos sea `image`.

```
{% for object in object_list.all %}
    <img src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

Creo que es esto lo que buscas.